Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation - Ubuntu 24.04 and derivatives
I have an HP ZBook 15 G5 that I am trying to install Ubuntu on, but when booting the ISO using BalenaEtcher, I receive the "Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation" pop up and cannot proceed further.
Unfortunately, this machine has a BIOS admin password that I do not have access to or know of. This means there is no feasible way for me to disable secure boot at the moment. With that said, the only ISOs that actually boot have been Fedora 40, and Linux Mint 22, and OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 (have not tried 15.6), which all have Shim 15.8 (please correct me if I am wrong).
From what I can gather, it seems like this something I will have to wait for with Ubuntu 24.10 and later versions in the future due to Shim 15.8 not being present in Ubuntu 24.04's ISO? Would it be possible getting it to work with 24.04? If any help or advice can be given, that would be greatly appreciated.

You need the BIOS password. Inquire of the computer maker how to get in if you do not have it.
